# unmet dependencies libsdl2-2.0-0

Tags: apt, dependencies, arm, arm64

the following problem is driving me crazy - I literally can't use apt right now because this issue appears whenever I try to update/upgrade/install a package (apt --fix-broken install ect. is not working either)

environment is arm64 ubuntu 64bit on my raspberry

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavdevice58 : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.12+dfsg1) but 2.0.10+5rpi is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to find the package which is causing this issue / removing related packages but also this is not working

```
sudo apt-get remove libavdevice58
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavdevice-dev : Depends: libavdevice58 (= 7:4.3.1-4ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove libavdevice-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavdevice58 : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.12+dfsg1) but 2.0.10+5rpi is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I know that this issue is caused by packages I installed manually for emulation station but I don't know how to fix this issue.
I tried to boot into recovery mode but until today I didn't figure out how to do this on the raspberry.

Let me know if any of you knows this issue or if there is a common way to fix it. If not I will most likely reinstall the OS.

BR
Lukas

Comment: Read your output: You used the wrong package name

Comment: same behaviour for libavdevice58 package, it doesn't matter which package I choose, I always get the same notification.

Comment: The problem is with `libsdl2-2.0-0`. Remove the non-Ubuntu, incompatible version that you manually installed. Try apt first. If apt fails, then use dpkg to do it. You may (or may not) need to uninstall all of emulation station, since you seem to have installed a version that is *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Installing wrong-version software that breaks the system is a moderately common new-user mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post, but this seemed to work for me. After attempting to install RetroPie in Ubuntu 22.04 on rpi4b, I ran into the same problems.I couldn't upgrade anything in terminal because of the, libavdevice58, libsdl2-2.0-0, and libsdl2-dev packages. I went into Synaptic Package Manager
and marked libavdevice58 to be reinstalled, then marked both libsdl2-2.0-0 and
libsdl2-dev to be upgraded. After a reboot the process went through for me and emulationstation seems to boot. Haven't tested anything further yet and hope this helps. Note: You can remove the said packages with, "sudo apt-get remove package_name". Start with libsdl2-dev.